# Override webpage centered

Tags: angularjs, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Angular Drywall to build my website. The default alignment of this is in the center. However, the template I want to render, requires to occupy 100% of the body width.
I used in css,

```
body{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

This does render yellow to the entire viewing area. But the content in my template is still rendered to the center.

How do I override that ?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I do not have a lot of code. I have attached two picture of how it looks and how I want it to look.

```
  <h1>Work Bench </h1>


<div class="col-lg-3 left">
     <div class="input-group resize">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Element"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

[image: What I expect]

[image: What it looks like]

Comment: do you have an image, jsfiddle or codepen example?

Comment: Kindly provide more code to the inner content.

Comment: I cannot make a fiddle, because it is an existing project I am using. Angular Drywall: https://github.com/arthurkao/angular-drywall

Comment: Seems like the elements aren't placed in the content div. The content div should have the same width and position like the footer.

Comment: @herrh I want the content to be rendered beyond the width of the footer and occupy the entire page. The first image is how I want it.

Comment: Ah okay. If you are using bootstrap, you just need to place your elements outside of the container classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap solution:

Close the container or container-fluid div and reopen it after placing your content betweeen.

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- navigation bar stuff -->
</div>

your elements here

<div class="container">
    <!-- footer stuff -->
</div>
```

[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/3QHTBEx931)

Comment: Thanks a ton. That is exactly what I want.

Comment: Glad I could help you ;)